# zlib compression on floats in a struct

Tags: c++, compression, byte, zlib

I have been searching along for a way to compress, using the zlib library (and the function `compress`) a struct containing float vars.

Every example I saw are showing how to compress a string, specifically an `unsigned char*`.

My struct is an easy one :

```
struct Particle{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
```

And I am calling the compress function as below :

```
uLong initSize = sizeof(Particle);
uLongf destSize = initSize * 1.1 + 12;
Bytef *dataOriginal = (Bytef*)malloc( initSize );
Bytef *dataCompressed = (Bytef*)malloc( destSize );

Particle p;
memset( &p, 0, sizeof(Particle) );

p.x = 10.24;
p.y = 23.5;
p.z = 7.4;

memcpy( dataOriginal, &p, sizeof(p) );
compress( dataCompressed, &destSize, dataOriginal, initSize );
```

But when I try to uncompress my data to see what inside, I can't get back to my initial float value :

```
Bytef *decomp = (Bytef*)malloc( initSize );
uncompress( decomp, &initSize, dataCompressed, destSize );

for( int i = 0 ; i < initSize ; i++ ){
    std::cout << (float)decomp[i] << std::endl;
}
```

If anyone have a solution to this problem, I'm on it since 2 days now...

Comment: erm, what is `initSize * 1.1 + 12` supposed to be?

Comment: (1) any solution to *what* problem (2) were you expecting the `Bytef decomp` pointer (which we don't even have a definition for) to magically *become* a valid float with that cast?

Comment: initSize * 1.1 + 12 is supposed to be the buffer size used by zlib to compress datas. I saw in several website that it must follow this rule. destSize is updated by zlib with the final size of the compressed datas after compress function has been call.

Comment: did you check what is return code for both `compress()` and `uncompress()`? If it is not Z_OK (0), you may have an explanation

Comment: Well, in fact I'm searching a solution to compress float datas contained in a struct with zlib.

Comment: the two functions compress and uncompress returned me a Z_OK code

Comment: Bytef is a zlib type define like this :
typedef unsigned char Byte;
typedef Byte Bytef;

Comment: So you're trying to compress effectively 24 bytes of data (assuming 64-bit floats). Exactly what kinda of savings ratio are you expecting to get from a Huffman compressed block where the source data is only 24 bytes long?

Comment: @WhozCraig In fact i'm trying to create a PRT file to import in Krakatoa, a 3D particle software. The PRT structure is define on this site : [link](http://www.thinkboxsoftware.com/krak-prt-file-format/)
My header is good but for the particle datas I need to compress them, as asked by the file structure.
I'm working with float32

Comment: Actually, IEEE float is 4 byte long (double is 8 bytes). so this struct should be only 12 bytes in size

Comment: @mvp Yeah, initSize is equals to 12 bytes (3*4)

Comment: @mvp heh. even better. alMAC, according to that spec I don't see a specific call to compress each individual trio of floats. Rather it looks like the entire bank of particles are compressed as a single block. Nor does it use `compress`; they specify the basic `zstream_p`-based `deflate` API, and compress the entire stream of particles before calling `deflateEnd`. you may want to rethink this a little to get more inline with their specification.

Comment: @WhozCraig First of all thanks for your answers. On the PRT file format link i read that "The particles are byte-packed one after another". For the compress function, as far as I can tell, it is an easy way to call a zstream object and the deflate function with all default values.

Comment: @aIMAC I believe you're correct that they are in fact byte-packed *before* the compression and/or submitted as a packed byte stream to the `deflate` stream. once you're finished sending them *all*, `deflateEnd` will finalize the stream and your resulting compressed data is finished. At least that is how I read it. I only bring it up because that will have a significantly different data representation than compressed particles one at a time. It may deserve a question to their KB guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to copy the decompressed data back into the Particle struct, just like you copied it out in the first place.  (Or you could just use casts instead of copies).  Then you will recover the original floats in the struct.  Whatever it is you think you're doing with 'decomp[i]` doesn't make any sense.

However there are several problems with this.  First, this is only assured to work on the same machine, with the same compiler, and even then only within the same version of the compiler.  If a different compiler or different version chooses to align the structure differently, then the compressed data will not be transferrable between the two.  If there is a different representation of floats between different machines, the compressed data will not be transferrable.

Furthermore, you will not get any compression when compressing three floats.  I presume that this is just a prelude to compressing a large array of such Particle structs.  Then maybe you'll get somewhere with this.

Better would be to first convert the floats to the precision needed as integers.  You should know the range and the useful number of bits for your application.  This will compress before even using `compress()`, by using only the number of bits needed as opposed to 32 per float.  Then convert those integers portably to a series of bytes with shift operations.  You can then also apply differencing to successive Particles (e.g. x1-x2, y1-y2, z1-z2), which might improve compression if there is a correlation between successive Particles.

By the way, instead of `* 1.1 + 12`, you should use `compressBound()`, which does exactly what you want in a way that is assured by the zlib library for future versions.

Comment: Transferring compressed integers between SPARC and Intel, say, is not portable either.  Portability of the compressed data is a separate from 'how to compress non-string data'.

Comment: It is if you do what I said: "Then convert those integers portably to a series of bytes with shift operations."  (You elected to not fully read my answer before adding your two cents.)

Comment: The original poster did not specify why they want to compress.  If it is for use within the same machine, then portability is not (much of) an issue.  If it is for transfer or storage, then portability of the compressed data is part of the question of "how to compress".

Comment: Thanks @MarkAdler , I can now uncompress and display my datas.
In fact this little program will be used to create a well formated PRT file which will be read in a 3D software. So yes there will be an Particle array to compress.